# How to update position of each child of a group in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a group and when I drag and drop that group only `group.position` is changing. It's child's positions is still the initial values. They are  not changing after drag and drop. How will I update the new position of each child?

```
group=new THREE.Group();
group.add(mesh1);`enter code here`
group.add(mesh2);
group.add(mesh3);
```

Suppose before translation 
`group.postion`:

position: THREE.Vector3
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0

`group.children[0].position`

x: -160.73611832689494
y: 56.06755614280701
z: 87.78444211930037

`group.children[1].position`

x: -29.662676970474422
y: 54.55312106758356
z: 14.629093836992979

after drag and drop:

`group.postion`

position: THREE.Vector3
x: -74.16755189596836
y: 0
z: -0.6893904394708485

`group.children[0].position`

x: -160.73611832689494
y: 56.06755614280701
z: 87.78444211930037

`group.children[1].position`

x: -29.662676970474422
y: 54.55312106758356
z: 14.629093836992979

pls give me a sloution..
How to update the matrix and get the new values of children's?

Comment: The groups children position is in local space, which means relative to the parent group. Do you know of ```getWorldPosition()```?

Comment: no.do you know any tutorial which explain world coordinates and local coordinate and how to update that?

Answer (score 3):

First of all - there are no more THREE.Group in latest THREE.JS revisions (r71). However you can use `THREE.Object3D` instead to group your objects:

```
var group=new THREE.Object3D();
group.add(box);
group.add(sphere);
scene.add(group);
```

Next, since you making translation for group - local position of objects (inside that group) does not changed. If you need to get global position of child object you can 
get it like this:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
vector.setFromMatrixPosition( box.matrixWorld );
```

or simplier:

```
box.matrixWorld.getPosition();
```

[here is a simple example](http://plnkr.co/edit/92gBm8F4oClpnRkbHL7x?p=preview)  at plnkr

Comment: thanks @SET .i understood your example.but what i need to do is.remove box from group after translation and still it preserver its new location.     console.log(group.position, box.position, vector);
  group.remove(box);
   scene.add(box);                         when i do this box is going back to its original position.i want to keep it in the translated position

Comment: chek script.js in this link @ SET ]http://plnkr.co/edit/fpjsUkOA0rH6FvG4DL6Z?p=preview

Comment: @JerrinaPaul, uncoment line with `sphere.position.copy(vector);`

Comment: can you check this link jsfiddle.net/jerrina/mLdet3c3 in this program i am trying to select some object by clicking on that object and dragging it some other location.frist time it will work.if i click on some object that is already moved to some other location it will go back to its original location.i could nt able to understand how to update world coordinates to resolve my issue @SET

Comment: @JerrinaPaul - http://jsfiddle.net/xe0d1n2o/2/. Anyway - your problem with messy code, not with updating position or parent/child manipulations.

Comment: your program is not working.i need to selectct a group object and need to move that to new location not a single object. can you please explain

Comment: @ SET do you have any demo of selecting objects and dragging and droping that

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/92gBm8F4oClpnRkbHL7x?p=preview when i remove comment line 57, 58 then the position of sphere1 is changing..can you expamin what to do to keep that postion even after removing the object from group;